# radially increasingly opaque overlay ellipse with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shading

Say I have a pattern on which I'd like a radially shaded (from transparent on the outside to white on the inside) so that the background pattern fades to white around the text.
How would I achieve this in TikZ?

This is an example without the shading:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {-2, -1.9, ..., 2}
{
 \draw[thin] (\x, 1) -- (\x, -1);
}
\fill[white] (0,0) ellipse (.5 and .25);
\node at (0,0) {bla};

\shade[shading=radial, inner color=white, outer color=transparent, opacity=.5] (-1,.5) ellipse (.5 and .25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm sure I could conjure up some sort of stack of semi-transparent ellipses with decreasing radius, but that seems kind of clunky (although it does achieve the intended effect). Is this at all possible using a radial shading directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buzzword for such things is `fadings` and there is a library for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{myshading}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!0);%
color(5mm)=(pgftransparent!10);%
color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!50);%
color(15mm)=(pgftransparent!100)%
}
\pgfdeclarefading{myfading}{\pgfuseshading{myshading}}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {-2, -1.9, ..., 2}{ \draw[thin] (\x, 1) -- (\x, -1);}

\node[ellipse,minimum width=1,minimum height=0.5,
     path fading=myfading,fill=white] at (0,0) {bla};
\fill[white,path fading=myfading] (-1,.5) ellipse (.5 and .25);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure your readers would appreciate this though. It needs an epilepsy seizure warning

Comment: The pattern in the example is just a quick test written up. The spacing is larger and the pattern more contained in the real figure. Thanks for your answer! It does show a sharp cutoff at the edge though, for some reason, which my stacked ellipse solution does not have. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, if you look at my shading definition at the top, I define how the transition would be depending on the distance from the center. I basically threw some numbers. You can play around with them or make smoother, or use an existing shading.

Comment: Right, but it seems you end at 0 or 100 so that should be smooth by itself. I'll play around a bit more with the numbers.

Comment: @rubenvb You can add more steps to make it smoother, here there is only 4 points.